# WordPress front page empty, however, there is content on website

Tags: themes, homepage

I am trying to set a simple informative WordPress site. I installed a theme called "**Stacy**" and trying to edit the home page now.

If I go to the `wp-admin -> pages -> Home -- Front Page` it seems to be empty, however, when I navigate to home page of my website or click or "preview changes" there is a full working home page already set.

Beginner with WordPress and this is driving me insane now...

**How can I edit the home page?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment yet, so I'll have to put this as an answer :-)

What do you see when you go to Settings / Reading, in the section that says "Your homepage displays"?

If it is set to "Your latest posts", the home page will be aggregating your post content and won't be using a particular page.

Another thing to check, when you go to the "Home -- Front Page", what is set under "Page Attributes" and "Templates" on the right hand side? If it is using a custom template, the content may all be coming from here?

Comment: Hi @junkrig ! Thanks for your interest. In the settings,I have it set as "Static Page". Also in the Front page I have template "Business Template", where is this template coming from and how can I edit it?

Comment: If it is the same "Stacy" theme that I'm looking at, the "Business Template" is in the Parent theme "spicepress", called template-business.php. This then references "index-news.php". Might be a bit fiddly but probably the best course of action to edit the template would be to create your own child theme and copy the business template from spice press, then make any changes you want.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes.
Otherwise you might be better off using a different theme?
Or just create another page using the "Default" template, and set this as the homepage in Settings / Reading.

Comment: Sorted my little friend. Created a child theme :P